# Пустой запрос laravel + backbone + json

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, laravel

Пишу API к серверу. Обращаюсь к этому API с backbone.js..

**Код ajax запроса..**

```
    var filter = {
        "type": 'testType',
        "isDone": 'testIsDone'
    };

    setupAjax: function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
             headers: {
                 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content')
             }
        });
    }

    $.ajax({

        beforeSend: this.setupAjax(),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        data: filter,
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://pr.lar/api/tasks',

        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        },
        error: function(res) {
            console.log(['error', res])
        }

    });
```

**Код сервера Laravel 5.2**

```
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;



class PartnerController extends Controller
{

   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->middleware('auth');
   }

   public function tasks(Request $request) {
       return $request;
   }

}
```

**Router**

```
Route::auth();
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'indexController@index']);
Route::get('/home', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);

$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1', function ($api) {
$api->group(['namespace' => 'App\Api\Controllers', 'middleware' => ['web']], 
function ($api) {

    $api->get('auth',                   'UserController@auth');

    $api->get('partners/{searchText}',  'PartnerController@search');
    $api->get('partner/{guid}',         'PartnerController@info');
    $api->get('tasks',                 'PartnerController@tasks');

});
```

});

**Получаю вот это.**

> **Object** { /api/tasks: "" }

Если передать без типа application/json простой post, либо get..
Получаю тоже самое..
Почему в теле request ничего нет?

Comment: пoробуй $request обернуть в `return response($request)`

Comment: Тоже самое, я никак не могу понять почему я получаю пустой request

Comment: А ты точно авторизован ?, какой статус у ответа?

Comment: Ты ж пишешь я так понимаю single page app ? как ты роуты писал? Нету там ничего такого что б перехватывало твой запрос раньше ? Сделай логирование в методе `\Log::info('Зашел в index');` и посмотри есть оно или нету в storage/logs/log.txt

Comment: Я использую dingo api.. У него есть свой роут, но ничего про входящий request в документации не сказано..

Comment: Сейчас добавлю router